# Use a backend web service or not

Tags: java, android, architecture, amazon-web-services, soa

We are building a new app that would require to store some data in S3 or DynamoDB. The number of users for this app would be relatively small (~ 500).

There are 2 ways of designing this.

1. We can either use the AWS SDK to persist information directly from the app
2. Build a back-end web service that talks to the data store and use HTTP to communicating with this service.

There are multiple pros and cons for each like Option #1 is way simpler and avoids a lot of overhead, Option #2 however is cleaner and provides better encapsulation. Also the back end web service could be used for any other task processing in the future.

Based on what aspects should once decide which option to choose ? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I'm not convinced that the overhead of Option 2 is worth it, so I would go with Option 1.

Keep in mind that Amazon S3 and DynamoDB **are** Web services (as explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Endpoints.html) for DynamoDB, same is true for S3). It's not like you're talking directly to a database through some specific port.

I would only go with Option 2 if I need to do server-side processing. If it's just for storing data, I would start with Option 1. You can always add the back-end service later.

Comment: +1, Keep it simple until you have a compelling reason to add complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 all the way forward, but give that back end service some role in your domain. Think SOA.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking only of "storing" in Dynamo, even option 1 will do. (Be aware that you need to keep the AWS secret and key in the app).

If you also need to "read" then option 2 is better, since you will get the flexibility of keeping a cache (like elastic cache) between your backend and dynamo to increase response times. Dynamo is "single region". Unless your read happens from the same region, then it is going to be very slow - latency issues. And this cache will help you reduce the cost of the dynamo, since you dont need to increase the throughput so high - Nothing is as fast as an in-memory cache !